# Office VBA- detect PowerPoint slide change

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint, slide

I'm creating an application where I'd like to be able to show users an ongoing PowerPoint presentation over the web, where the slide changes as the presenter does so in real time. I've looked at the Office VBA documentation and I didn't see any event for this. The closest I've come are [these events](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/PowerPoint-2010-Add-Series-fccd83cc), but I don't see anyway of doing what I need to using these.

How can I detect slide changes in Microsoft Powerpoint using Visual Basic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is what you are looking for: [Application.SlideShowNextSlide Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745863.aspx)

This is VBA Powerpoint object model though, but you should be able to find your way around...